# Python: Regex findall returns a list, why does trying to access the list element [0] return an error?

Tags: python, regex

Taken from the documentation, the following is a snippet showing how the regex method findall works, and confirms that it does return a list.

```
re.findall(r"\w+ly", text)
['carefully', 'quickly']
```

However the following code fragment generates an out of bounds error (`IndexError: list index out of range`)when trying to access the zeroth element of the list returned by findall.

Relevant Code Fragment:

```
population = re.findall(",([0-9]*),",line)
x = population[0]
thelist.append([city,x])
```

Why does this happen?

For some more background, here's how that fragment fits into my entire script:

```
import re

thelist = list()
with open('Raw.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[1].isdigit():
            city = re.findall("\"(.*?)\s*\(",line)
            population = re.findall(",([0-9]*),",line)
            x = population[0]
            thelist.append([city,x])

with open('Sorted.txt','w') as g:
    for item in thelist:
        string = item[0], ', '.join(map(str, item[1:]))
        print string
```

EDIT: Read comment below for some background on why this happened. My quick fix was:

```
if population: 
        x = population[0]
        thelist.append([city,x])
```

Comment: The regex will not always match and return an empty list sometimes

Comment: Running that fragment independently on the Python shell indicates that it does. The same input file is used as well.

Comment: obviously not for *all* lines.

Comment: In your script, you should do `print population` to ensure that you are, in fact, getting at least one match.

Comment: @Louis93: did you take empty lines into account?

Comment: I did not. Good catch people. I'll add my quick fix to the question.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, you should post it as an answer, rather than appending it to your question.

Comment: I found a fix, the answerer actually answers my original question which where I asked why this was happening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`re.findall` will return an empty list if there are no matches:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+ly', 'this does not work')
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

`re.findall` can return you an empty list in the case where there was no match.  If you try to access `[][0]` you will see that `IndexError`.

To take into account no matches, you should use something along the lines of:

```
match = re.findall(...)
if match:
  # potato potato
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The solution seems very simple, and I don't know why I wasn't considering it.

```
if match:
```

instead of

```
if match[0]:
```