# python: arrays produced by a regular expression in a loop "unexpected indent error"

Tags: python

when I run the following code I get an error "IdentationError: unexpected indent". But I don't know why and how can I solve it. the error is in the first if statement.

```
import re
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
UOB = [sheet.cell_value(r,14) for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
count = {}
Myset = set()
for x in range (sheet.nrows):
    match = re.findall(",*([\w]*[College]*[Department]*[\w ]*),[ ]        
[The]*Uni[\w.]*[ ]of[ ]Bahr[ai]*[ei]*n,*([\w ]*[College]*[Department]*[\w ]*),",UOB[x])
    if match[0][0]!='':
        if match[0][0] in Myset:
            count[match[0][0]]+=1  
        else:   
            Myset.add(match[0][0])
            count[match[0][0]]=1

    else:
        if match[0][1] in Myset:
            count[match[0][1]]+=1  
        else:   
            Myset.add(match[0][1])
            count[match[0][1]]=1
```

Comment: Fix your regex to be on single line

Comment: I see mixed tabs and spaces. Fix that. (I also see a malformed string literal that should have errored out before Python got to the indentation problems.)

Comment: That regex makes no sense. `[The]*`? `[College]*`? Both the character class and the `*` are inappropriate.

Comment: I have tried to change but I couldn't solve the problem

Comment: @user2357112 I changed the regex but couldn't find the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

set your string to a variable and clean it up to fit on multiple lines correctly:

```
z = (   ",*([\w]*[College]*[Department]*[\w ]*),"     +
        "[ ][The]*Uni[\w.]*[ ]of[ ]Bahr[ai]*[ei]*n,"  +
        "*([\w ]*[College]*[Department]*[\w ]*),"     )

for x in range (sheet.nrows):
    match = re.findall(z,UOB[x])
```

Comment: @sara if regex list is empty you can't index it, you probably need "if match" instead of 'if match[0][0]!=''' see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992787/python-regex-findall-returns-a-list-why-does-trying-to-access-the-list-element

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the regex